# I want to put variable in get String()

Tags: android

I trying to put string to textView so I did like this 
In R.string file

<R.string>

```
    <string name="GPS_info">Provider : %s &#10;longitude : %Lf &#10;latitude : %Lf
                &#10; altitude : %Lf &#10; accuracy : %Lf</string>
```

In MainActivity

<MainActivitiy>

```
tv.setText(getString(R.string.GPS_info, provider, latitude, longitude, altitude, accuracy));
```

but this caused unexpected error what did I wrong?

> ```
> ( 2246): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.playground/app.playground.MainActivity}: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: L
> ( 2246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
> ( 2246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
> ( 2246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
> ( 2246):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
> ( 2246):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> ( 2246):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
> ( 2246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
> ( 2246):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> ( 2246):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
> ( 2246):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
> ( 2246):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
> ( 2246):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ( 2246): Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: L
> ( 2246):    at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:1399)
> ( 2246):    at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.checkFlags(Formatter.java:1336)
> ( 2246):    at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1442)
> ( 2246):    at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
> ( 2246):    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
> ( 2246):    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
> ( 2246):    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1999)
> ( 2246):    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:359)
> ( 2246):    at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:356)
> ( 2246):    at app.playground.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
> ( 2246):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
> ( 2246):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> ( 2246):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
> ( 2246):    ... 11 more
> ```

Comment: What's the unexpected error ? Can you post the stack trace please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%Lf` format arguments are the problem. I'm not aware of any `L` character to be used for numeric format arguments (only for date arguments).

Change your string to

```
<string name="GPS_info">Provider : %s &#10;longitude : %f &#10;latitude : %f
            &#10; altitude : %f &#10; accuracy : %f</string>
```

Note also that in your string you have longitude before latitude, but in your java code you're passing latitude before longitude. This will mean lat/lng are swapped in the string, which shouldn't *break* anything, but won't be what you want.

Answer (score -1):

you should implement it like this:

```
tv.setText(getString(R.string.GPS_info)+ getString(R.string.provider));
```